# Python Class / NoneType

Tags: python, jython, nonetype

I've the following python function:

```
def run(value, args):
    offset = args[0]
    return offset.asInt()
```

If I return `type(offset)` I get a ClassName `org.python.core.PyInteger`. This class has methods like `asInt()`, `getValue()`, ... (It's a Jython class) But every time I call a method, I get an error:

```
NoneType object has no attribute ....
```

Full Error Message:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: AttributeError: "NoneType" object has no attribute "asInt" in script.py at line number 3
```

Comment: So *what line* throws the exception? You should really include the *full* traceback, not just the exception line.

Comment: Can you write and post a tiny program that reproduces the very same error?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple program that shows class type as 'str'(string class) below:

```
readFile = open("PATHtoFile", 'r')
data = readFile.read()
print(type(data))
<class 'str'>
```

Since, it's bad practice to leave the file open I will use the close method to close by doing the following:

```
data = readFile.close()
print(data)
None
print(type(data))
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Notice, that the class type is now 'NoneType' because there is nothing in the variable data that can be read since I use the close method?